# Timeout for incomplete HTTP requests

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I'm new to Envoy Filters and I want to set the timeout period for incomplete HTTP requests to be equal to or less than 40 seconds.

Envoy Filters provides HTTP connection manager extension where you can do :

```
common_http_protocol_options:
  idle_timeout: 40s
```

I'm not very confident if this is the solution to what I'm trying to implement since a lot of concepts are new to me. Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Which Istio version are you using? Could you please share a tutorial / documentation that are you referring to? Did you try to test this solution?

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using? What do you mean by `incomplete HTTP request`? How do you testing it? Could you please [make your issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?